# Why cosine distance is much slower than using euclidean distance with DBSCAN algo in scikitlearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am going to use two metrics (Euclidean distance and cosine similarity) for the DBSCAN algorithm from package `scikit-learn`.

The thing is that using Euclidean distance is much faster than using cosine similarity.

The code:

```
// using euclidean distance    
DBSCAN(eps=0.02, min_samples=5, metric="euclidean").fit(data)

// using cosine similarity
DBSCAN(eps=0.02, min_samples=5, metric=cosine_distance).fit(data)
```

Does anyone know the cause of this difference in speed with cosine similarity?

Comment: Is the function cosine_distance the one from sklearn.metrics.pairwise? That one is called ``cosine_distances``, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about `scikit-learn`, but I can guess why it might be slower from a mathematical perspective.

---

**Definitions**

Say you have two vectors with *n* dimensions (**A** and **B**).

The [**Euclidean distance** of two vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) is calculated as

```
Sqrt((A_1 - B_1)^2 + (A_2 - B_2)^2 + ... + (A_N - B_N)^2)
```

where `A_m` is the `m`<sup>th</sup> element in **A**. To calculate it, you need to calculate *n* differences, *n* products, and **1** square root.

The [**Cosine** of two vectors](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) is defined as

```
cos(x) = A.B / |A||B|
```

where

```
A.B = A_1 * B_1 + A_2 * B_2 + ...  A_n * B_n
|A| = Sqrt((A_1)^2 + (A_2)^2 + ... + (A_N)^2)
```

so *n* multiplications for `A.B` and 2.*n* multiplications to get `|A|` and `|B|`.

---

**Comparison**

The **Euclidean** distance requires *n* subtractions and *n* multiplications; the **Cosine** similarity requires 3.*n* multiplications.

Assuming subtraction is as computationally intensive (*it'll almost certainly be less intensive*), it's 2.*n* for Euclidean vs. 3.*n* for Cosine.

In other words, it's **at least 50% slower** to get the cosine difference than the Euclidean distance. I don't know how `scikit-learn` uses these metrics, or how large your *n* is, but that may be a reason why you're seeing a difference.

Comment: This is nice & true, and true for a single example, but most use cases are to find between  one object and multiple other objects, or repetitive. in  this case the norm of each vector can be stored along with the vector itself, so you can save norm for each vector for every iteration. In Euclidean dist, you won't be able to add this optimization,since the whole calculation is based on the 2 vectors together

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `cosine_distance` is a Python function:

While sklearn allows you to specify a custom distance function, the performance of this is not particularly great. For every distance, it needs to setup a callback into the Python *interpreter*. This naturally is much slower than the compiled native code used by the built-in functions.

This overhead doesn't seem to be resolved anytime soon with Python. It may be necessary to either modify the sklearn source (to add new built-ins) or to use something like Java with a good JIT (e.g., ELKI is extensible this way, and much faster for custom distances).

Jython sounds cool (Python on the JVM), but as far as I know does not support numpy and thus not sklearn either. And I don't know if it can compile Python into bytecode, or if it is just an interpreter.